# FreeWRL, "format not a string literal and no format arguments"

Tags: c, android-ndk, printf

So I'm trying to build the freewrl android library, which is in native android code, that means in C. I'm by no means familiar with C, and thought since there was a build-script included, it should work right out of the box. - It does not. 
After fixing some minor issues, this is what I'm looking at right now:

```
/opt/freewrl/Android/jni/../../freex3d/src/lib/main/ConsoleMessage.c: In function 'fwvsnprintf':
/opt/freewrl/Android/jni/../../freex3d/src/lib/main/ConsoleMessage.c:333:4: error: format not a string literal and no format arguments [-Werror=format-security]
cc1: some warnings being treated as errors
make: *** [/opt/freewrl/Android/obj/local/armeabi/objs/FreeWRL/__/__/freex3d/src/lib/main/ConsoleMessage.o] Error 1
```

The code in ConsoleMessage.c which is relevant is the following:

```
count += sprintf(tempbuf, format);/* printf it verbatim             */
```

Which is part of the following construct or function:

```
int fwvsnprintf(char *buffer,int buffer_length, const char *fmt, va_list ap)
{
    int i,j,count;
    //char tempbuf[STRING_LENGTH];
    //char format[STRING_LENGTH];
    char *tempbuf;
    char *format;
    char c;
    double d;
    unsigned u;
    char *s;
    void *v;
    tempbuf = malloc(buffer_length);
    format = malloc(buffer_length);
    count = 0;
    buffer[0] = '\0';
    while (*fmt) 
    {
        tempbuf[0] = '\0';
        for (j = 0; fmt[j] && fmt[j] != '%'; j++) {
            format[j] = fmt[j]; /* not a format string  */
        }

        if (j) {
            format[j] = '\0';
            count += sprintf(tempbuf, format);/* printf it verbatim             */
            fmt += j;
        } else {
            for (j = 0; !isalpha(fmt[j]); j++) {     /* find end of format specifier */
                format[j] = fmt[j];
                if (j && fmt[j] == '%')             /* special case printing '%'        */
                    break;
            }
            format[j] = fmt[j];         /* finish writing specifier      */
            format[j + 1] = '\0';           /* don't forget NULL terminator */
            fmt += j + 1;

            switch (format[j]) {             /* cases for all specifiers         */
            case 'd':
            case 'i':                       /* many use identical actions    */
                i = va_arg(ap, int);         /* process the argument     */
                count += sprintf(tempbuf, format, i); /* and printf it       */
                break;
            case 'o':
            case 'x':
            case 'X':
            case 'u':
                u = va_arg(ap, unsigned);
                count += sprintf(tempbuf, format, u);
                break;
            case 'c':
                c = (char) va_arg(ap, int);     /* must cast!            */
                count += sprintf(tempbuf, format, c);
                break;
            case 's':
                s = va_arg(ap, char *);
                /* limit string to a certain length */
                if ((strlen(s) + count) > buffer_length) {
                    char tmpstr[100];
                    int ltc;
                    ltc = (int) strlen(s);
                    if (ltc>80) ltc=80;
                    strncpy (tmpstr, s, ltc);
                    tmpstr[ltc] = '.'; ltc++;
                    tmpstr[ltc] = '.'; ltc++;
                    tmpstr[ltc] = '.'; ltc++;
                    tmpstr[ltc] = '\0';

                    count += sprintf (tempbuf, format, tmpstr);
                } else count += sprintf(tempbuf, format, s);
                break;
            case 'f':
            case 'e':
            case 'E':
            case 'g':
            case 'G':
                d = va_arg(ap, double);
                count += sprintf(tempbuf, format, d);
                break;
            case 'p':
                v = va_arg(ap, void *);
                count += sprintf(tempbuf, format, v);
                break;
            case 'n':
                count += sprintf(tempbuf, "%d", count);
                break;
            case '%':
                count += sprintf(tempbuf, "%%");
                break;
            default:
                ERROR_MSG("ConsoleMessage: invalid format specifier: %c\n", format[j]);
            }
        }
        if( (strlen(tempbuf) + strlen(buffer)) < (buffer_length) -10) 
        {
            strcat (buffer,tempbuf);
        }
    }
    free(tempbuf);
    free(format);
    return 1;
}
```

So as far as I can see, `format` is filled with the contents of `fmt`, which is an argument, until a `%` is read. `tempbuf` seems like a '\0' so a null byte to me.
But this is as far as I get with this, so I'd appreciate any help, as I'm struggling to build this library.
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As per error it seems that in your `makefile` the `-Werror=format-security` flag is enable by default and it's very good to not cause any security issue for string format like in `printf` or `scanf` function.So the warning treated as error in your source. So if you not worry about security then disable it. Or please make change in code everywhere the same statement found as follows might be it remove error.

```
count += sprintf(tempbuf,"%s",format);/* printf it verbatim             */
```

For safe use `snprintf` like

```
count += snprintf(tempbuf,buffer_length,"%s",format);/* printf it verbatim             */
```

Comment: Thank you! The "%s" fixed it.